# WCF tries to convert an internal class to DataContract?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I have an operation with this definition:

```
[OperationContract]
ResponseEntity SaveMeasurements(string token, Entity sample);
```

Here's the abridged implementation code:

```
public ResponseEntity SaveMeasurements(string token, MetroSampleEntity sample)
{
    // some other code goes here
    provider.Query(new SampleDataTable());
}
```

I am getting this error:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:dt. The InnerException message was 'Type '' with data contract name 'SampleDataTable:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

I am trying to use `SampleDataTable` for internal transaction, but WCF is picking it up as data contract...or at least try to. Is there's a way I can tell WCF NOT to process `SampleDataTable` as part of the contract?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Marc for the lead.
The provider object in the code is actually another WCF client whose query call accepts the DataTable type. Though `SampleDataTable` extends `DataTable`, the `Query()` will NOT "recognize it."

Comment: It isn't clear to me that the problem here is SampleDataTable - that doesn't seem to be involved in the WCF layer here, unless `provider` is also a WCF stub. I'm guessing MetroSampleEntity is the real problem here (is that declared as a known type of Entity?). But: if you want to send data over a WCF bridge, it needs to understand the data so it can serialize it, so no: you can't just ignore data if you want it to get from A to B. If you have specific properties/fields on a data type that you don't want to send: you can invite *those properties/fields*, sure.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the lead...it just dawns on me that the provider is another WCF client.  Though, the call Query() accepts the type DataTable, it doesn't accept any other type that extends the DataTable.

Comment: Then: don't *send* another type other than`DataTable` :) however, I have to note: sending `DataTable` over WCF smells a lot of defeating the point... Usually, typed data like a `List<T>` for some `T` would be preferred